# How to show multiple objectives for multiple players in tab in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

My brother has a Minecraft server and he wants to show multiple scores for each player in the tab menu (setdisplay list). Is this possible to set up in vanilla Minecraft and how would one go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is only ever one objective in each display slot. You could either combine then somehow (like with additional dummy entities) or use different display slots (sidebar, below name, …).